# How to pass or freeze a point in time value to a task?

Tags: .net, task

How to pass or freeze a point in time value to a task?

The problem the code below is the SID passed to DocFTSinXsCollection(SID) is NOT when Task.Factory.StartNew was executed rather the SID from the next rdr.Read().

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
     SID = rdr.GetInt32(0);
     // other code
     Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
         // this often gets the new  SID - I need the SID from when Task was started
         DocFTSinXsCollection docFTSinXsCollection = new DocFTSinXsCollection(SID);
     }
     // other code
}
```

Comment: In the posted code there is only **one** variable called SID. So the **same** variable is bound in each closure ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare `SID` as a local variable within the `while` loop so that each closure will get its *own* variable:

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
     int SID = rdr.GetInt32(0);
     // other code
     Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
         // this often gets the new  SID - I need the SID from when Task was started
         DocFTSinXsCollection docFTSinXsCollection = new DocFTSinXsCollection(SID);
     }
     // other code
}
```

Comment: Testing now and so far so good.  Need to test some more before accepting. SLaks you have helped me before and ways thanks!